# CONVERT HEADER INTO <img>

Tags: php, header, gd, image

I'd like to show the image in this page using an `<img>` tag instead of an header (    **header("content-type: image/jpeg");**   ). any ideas?

```
<?php  

$main_img       = "Porsche_911_996_Carrera_4S.jpg"; // main big photo / picture
$watermark_img  = "watermark.gif"; // use GIF or PNG, JPEG has no tranparency support
$padding        = 3; // distance to border in pixels for watermark image
$opacity        = 50;   // image opacity for transparent watermark

$watermark  = imagecreatefromgif($watermark_img); // create watermark
$image      = imagecreatefromjpeg($main_img); // create main graphic

if(!$image || !$watermark) die("Error: main image or watermark could not be loaded!");


$watermark_size     = getimagesize($watermark_img);
$watermark_width    = $watermark_size[0];  
$watermark_height   = $watermark_size[1];  

$image_size     = getimagesize($main_img);  
$dest_x         = $image_size[0] - $watermark_width - $padding;  
$dest_y         = $image_size[1] - $watermark_height - $padding;


// copy watermark on main image
imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity);


// print image to screen
header("content-type: image/jpeg");   
imagejpeg($image);  
imagedestroy($image);  
imagedestroy($watermark);
?>
```

Comment: So, when you call the file, it outputs HTML with an `<img>` tag displaying the image?

Comment: Like this? `<img src="example.php"/>` where example.php is the name of your PHP file.

Comment: Kind of obvious now:) THanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script generates an image, its output is an image, so you can use it in a tag, but in an other page:

```
<img src="image.php" /> <!-- (if image.php is the name of the script you posted) -->
```

Comment: Thanks!-That's the best answer due to the comment:)

Answer (score 3):

```
<img src="yourscript.php"/>
```

or have your script output the image in some file and then use this file.

Comment: Thanks!-lots of same answers:)

Answer (score 3):

> any ideas?

Don't do it. It is theoretically possible to embed images in HTML using [`data:` URI's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data%20URI), but it has too many downsides and is usually a bad idea. The classical approach using an `<img>` tag that references the PHP script is the way to go.

Comment: @Wide I think you are actually looking to do exactly what I recommend :) I understood your question to mean something else. Never mind

Comment: @Pekka-You gave it a shot-I appreciate your time mate!

Answer (score 1):

you work with the `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()`

```
if($_GET['image'])
{
ob_start();
$main_img       = "a.jpg"; // main big photo / picture
$watermark_img  = "b.gif"; // use GIF or PNG, JPEG has no tranparency support
$padding        = 3; // distance to border in pixels for watermark image
$opacity        = 50;   // image opacity for transparent watermark

$watermark  = imagecreatefromgif($watermark_img); // create watermark
$image      = imagecreatefromjpeg($main_img); // create main graphic

if(!$image || !$watermark) die("Error: main image or watermark could not be loaded!");


$watermark_size     = getimagesize($watermark_img);
$watermark_width    = $watermark_size[0];  
$watermark_height   = $watermark_size[1];  

$image_size     = getimagesize($main_img);  
$dest_x         = $image_size[0] - $watermark_width - $padding;  
$dest_y         = $image_size[1] - $watermark_height - $padding;


// copy watermark on main image
imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, $opacity);


// print image to screen

header("content-type: image/jpeg");   
imagejpeg($image);  
imagedestroy($image);  
imagedestroy($watermark);
$s = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
 echo $s;
 }
 ?>
 [img src="echo '?image=1'?>"]
```

at the end you can in the src of image tage do this
`echo '?image=1'`